# Angular & Firebase - is it possible to use a query in a resolver?

Tags: angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

**What I'm using**

- Angular
- Firebase

**What I'm trying to achieve**

- Display items in order of date (a key in firebase "project_date". See screenshot below of node title)[image]

**Issues**

- I'm currently using a resolver to return my items
- Is it possible to merge a query/sort into my resolver?

**My Project List Resolver**

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
import { AuthService } from '../../user/auth.service';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/first';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()

export class ProjectsListResolver {

  constructor(private database: AngularFireDatabase, private authService: AuthService) { }

 
  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> {

    return Observable.create(observer => {

      this.authService.user
        .first()
        .subscribe(user => {
          this.database.list(`/project_list/${user.uid}`)
            .first()
            .subscribe(projectList => {
              observer.next(projectList);
              observer.complete();
            });
        });
    });
  }

}
```

**Projects Component TS**

```js
ngOnInit() {

    // Returns the data from the projects list resolver
    this.activatedRoute.data
      .subscribe((
        data: { projectListData: any }) => {
        this.projectsList = data.projectListData;
      });
  }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I do that with my application. First of all when you get the data from the Firebase , it is json so you have to  change it to array , then you have to sort the array depending on date. This is  the sorting function:

```
 arr.sort((a: any [], b: any []) => {

        return (new Date (a[0]) .getTime() - new Date (b[0]).getTime()) ;
      });
```

If you want the full code , I can post it.

Comment: Hey Zahmed. Thank you for such a quick response. If you don't mind, that would be great. I'm exceptionally new to this, so it's a bit of a step learning curve, How it would integrate with my code above would be fantastic thank you. I've just updated my post to include code from my projects component file, if that adds to how this would work overall.

Comment: See the time-attendance class  , there is a function called : AttendanceTime()....

This is the link: https://github.com/AhmadZeid10/HRSystem/tree/master/src/app/manger

Comment: Thanks @ZAhmed. Appreciate you posting the code. Unfortunately this is a bit advanced for me. (I only started learning this stuff a month ago..)